# Android System.loadLibrary crash in libhoudini (ARM translator on x86)

Tags: android, x86, java-native-interface, arm

My .so JNI library causes Android application to crash at loading time (call to System.loadLibrary) when ran on x86 Android. On ARM it's working fine.

The error in logcat is:
houdini﹕ [12251] Unsupported feature (ID:0x20e00149).

Houdini is an ARM translator for x86, so probably I'm using something that cannot be translated.

Obviously I can modify the code of my .so library co maybe I can change whatever the problem is, but how to investigate that? How could I know what part of my code is causing the problem?

Oh, and by the way - is any code from .so ran at loading time? Maybe some variable initializers?

Comment: Did you used some NEON code? Some instruction sets aren't available.

Answer (score 0):

a bit of internet search show that libhoundini is proprietary code (**ask the vendor for support**)

but yea, like all java native libraries, 
it would probebly have a onload function.
something like: `JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *jvm, void *reserved)`
so, probebly it is what is causing the problem, because it is executed when the library is loaded.

Comment: There's a lot more code that can be executed during loading the SO library - think about .init_array which is normally responsible for initialization of static variables.